# Using simple javascript and passing arguments with Rails3 and UJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

I have watched railscasts about unobtrusive javascript and read numerous tutorials, but two things about unobtrusive javascript in Rails3 still confuses me:

1. End-point for simple javascript (hiding some elements, adding CSS class, ...)
2. Passing arguments to JS

Let me clarify this with sample code. I want to make a link which fades out some element with id "sample":

```
link_to 'Fade sample', url, :remote => true
```

What should be the url so it can execute JS? Should it be new action in controller named for example 'javascript' so it can access JS in javascript.js.erb which contains:

```
$('#sample').fadeOut();
```

Also, second question about ujs is related with passing arguments to JS (timeout, for this example). I can write:

```
link_to 'Fade sample', url, :data-timeout => 1500, :remote => true
```

but don't know how to access data-timeout in javascript.

I am using Rails 3.0.5, JQuery 1.5.2 and jquery-ujs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to answer one by one.

1. url in `link_to`. It would be a url hash for any resource in the application. Lets suppose you have specified `resources :foos` in the routes.rb, it will create 6 urls for CRUD operation. You can pass these to the urls by the methods like `new_foo_url`, `foo_url(@foo)` or `foos_url`. Even you can pass a hash manually like `{:controller=>:foos_controller, :action=>:index}`, also you can pass multiple parameters to the hash like `{:controller=>:foos_controller, :action=>:index, :param1=>"value1", :param2=>"value2"}`. Also you can pass strings urls like `foos/new`, `foos/1` etc
2. You can access custom tag attributes with jQuery very easily. for example you want to access anchor with `id="link"`, you can `$('#link').attr("data-timeout")`. If you don't know what exactly the id is, but you know it have an attribute you can call `$("a[data-timeout]").first().attr('data-timeout')`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regarding first answer, I can understand url, but I don't know what url should it be when I want to specify not some resource, but javascript. Should it be some new action in controller named for example 'showing' in which case javascript file should be located in showing.js.erb?

In this example, I don't need to get some resources, I just want to execute simple javascript code.

Comment: You can uncomment the last line in `routes.rb` file `match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'`. After that you can just define any method in controller can use it in link_to. As you said function `something`, you can pass it with the hash `{:controller=>:some_controller, :action=>:something}`.

Comment: I would suggest if you have a lot of js handling in your application, you must define a single function for it, and pass params to it. e.g. i would define an action js_handler in the controller. now i gave hash `{:controller=>:my_controller, :action=>js_handler, :what_to_do=>'task1'}` and in your method you can use these params to perform different actions.

Comment: Thank you, Nazar. This last comment helped me. This was an option but i didn't know if it is a 'proper' solution to my problem. Thank you.